# Suspicious activity on port 3389. Has my system been compromised?

Tags: security, windows-7, rdp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Today I opened TCPView to see what was causing a lot of outbound network activity and could only identify svchost.exe on port 3389 (which i understand to be the port used by remote desktop).

I ended the process almost immediately.

I've searched for the IP address it was connected to, and discovered it originates in South Korea.

I have just discovered in the Windows Event Viewer under "Applications and Services Log > Microsoft > Windows > TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager" almost 2,000 events which read similar to:

```
Remote Desktop Services: User authentication succeeded:

User: administrator
Domain: 
Source Network Address: 1.214.253.235
```

I wanted to know if my system has indeed been compromised and whether it is at all possible for me to track any activity; such as file access.

What is the best course of action to take to prevent this happening in future. Or haven't I anything to worry about.

Comment: As a home user, you are likely to get better answers geared toward a home setting at our sister site Super User. Server Fault is intended for professional settings, and often the answers which work for a business don't do so well in a home setting and vice versa. Though, this sort of question is fairly commonly asked so you may want to search there as well.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure where to post this. I'll try over at Super User too

Comment: If you submit the problem to SuperUser SE, please delete this message.  Duplicate questions on different SEs are frowned upon.

Comment: Have voted for deletion as super user exchange is more appropriate being a home user.

Answer (score 7):

It says Administrator successfully logged in via Remote Desktop from somewhere in South Korea. If the administrator isn't in South Korea, you've been compromised.